# ConstraintLayout Problems using <include>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to figure out why this does not work. I am adding nothing but two `<include>` sections in a `ConstraintLayout` and the layout is not following any of the constraints that I set up. I am trying to begin migrating to the use of `ConstraintLayout` as my go-to layout, but things like this keep pushing me back to `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.

Here is the top level layout file (the ConstraintLayout), showing some of the constraints that are not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeButton"
        layout="@layout/include_button_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeText"
        layout="@layout/include_text_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
```

Here is the first included layout (include_button_panel):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/include_button_panel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Touch me!" />

</merge>
```

Here is the second included layout (include_text_panel):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/include_text_panel_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7986cb"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is the text panel"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</merge>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the `<merge>` tag from both of your included layouts.

When you specifiy attributes on an `<include>` tag, the system will apply those attributes to the root view of the included layout. The `<merge>` tag is a special element to allow you to have multiple views in your layout *without* having a root view. So all of your constraints get thrown out when your included layout uses the `<merge>` tag. Luckily, both of your included layouts only have one view inside the merge, so you can just remove the merge altogether.

Comment: What do you do when you don't use merge tags but the `<include>` layout still ignores constraints in its parent? I'm having this exact problem.

Comment: For anyone wondering, the answer to my problem was that I didn't include `android:layout_width` & `android:layout_height` in my `<include>` declaration in the parent layout. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43625651/android-add-other-layout-in-constraintlayout-using-include-tag/43656852

Answer (score 13):

try this Remove the `<merge>` tag from both of your included layouts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeButton"
        layout="@layout/include_button_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeText"
        layout="@layout/include_text_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

As Cody mentioned in comments , the problem may be that **you are not setting `layout_width`  and `layout_height` for your included layout** , witch doesn't produce any editor errors , but constraints don't work any more.